# the signed measure defined by a bounded variation process

Tags: probability, measure-theory

We know that any real function with bounded variation defines a signed measure on the Borelians of R, and that it is possible to integrate against a bounded variation function by integrating against its signed measure.

I also know that is it possible to integrate against a (random) process as long as it has bounded variations. But in that case, how is defined the actual signed measure related to the process?

As an example, the process A(t) : t |--> Maximum of a Brownian motion between 0 and t, has bounded variations, and I want to prove that it cannot be written as an Ito process. I can see that the issue is that A(t) can stay constant at a certain value, and the Lebesgue measure is 0 for any singleton, but I'm really confused as what is the signed measure that is given by A(t). Can somebody explain this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The running maximum of a Brownian motion is not a diffusion, for example because it does not possess the Markov property.